# Scheduling a background NSURLSessionDataTask while running in background

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

Ok, this sounds crazy... but I have a scenario where I'd like to use the NSURLSession system to schedule a background data task, in the case where my app is being launched in the background via a remote notification.

What I'm observing is that after I schedule the task, and resume it, when I call the fetchCompletionHandler, my task never actually executes.

If I simply delay the call to the fetchCompletionHandler by a couple seconds, then my task actually executes.

Is it supported to schedule a background download when already running in the background?

I'm aware I could also just use an ordinary async request, and call the fetchCompletionHandler when the request finishes, but I'd like to have a single system for this particular request, and not have to special-case it in the case the app is launched in the background.